# show a section of the current url as link in the same page using javascript and/or php

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say I have a site with url https://stackoverflow.com/index.php#https://example.com/image.jpg and I want to display the image at https://example.com/image.jpg in my site (https://stackoverflow.com/index.php) .

I have tried the following but it gives the url of image only.

```
<p id="image"></p> <script>
         document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = window.location.hash.replace('#','');

</script>
```

I want the following output (Or similar to show the image)

```
<img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" alt="Image">
```

Comment: If that's what you want, then why aren't you creating an `img` element somewhere? `.innerHTML` just inserts text between the start and end tags of a given element.

Comment: How is this related to PHP in any way?

Comment: I'm sorry that I flagged your question as SPAM. I got confused by the Youtube redirections in your links. My bad! To whom may be interested to understand what's going on : https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-stackoverflow-com-admin-PHP-page-redirect-to-a-new-YouTube-video-every-time

Comment: @DavidGuyon, is this related to "Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more." I'm getting this message, I tried using VPN but still nothing is happening. Do I need to create a new account ?

Comment: @DotBotHCV, I don't know what is happening with your account. Here's some information about this error : https://stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block. I'd suggest you to contact the support with the Help Center (https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to know more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substring and indexOf to extract the url after the #. Also change the src only instead of the whole innerhtml.

## Working snippet with string as URL

```js
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/index.php#https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf"

document.getElementById("image").src = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
```

```html
<img id="image" src="" alt="Image">
```

## Non working snippet, but clear solution.

```js
var url = window.location.href

document.getElementById("image").src = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
```

```html
<img id="image" src="" alt="Image">
```

Comment: I need to get the image from the URL, the only way I can get the image is from the URL itself.

Comment: I don't get your problem? replace url string with "window.location.hash"?

Answer (score -1):

Use `.src` instead of `.innerHtml`

If you want to get the hash from URL directly then can use

```
document.getElementById("image").src = window.location.hash.replace('#','')
```

Or if it is a variable instead

```
var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/index.php#https://example.com/image.jpg'
document.getElementById("image").src = url.split('#')[1]
```

**HTML**

Use `<img>` tag instead of `<p>` tag

```
<img id="image" alt"image name">
```

Comment: @Wimanicesir Did you notice the question of OP? His main issue was `innerHtml`. I thought he wanted to get the hash from URL not from a variable.

Comment: @MH2K9 I want to get the hash from URL, but your solution is not working. The image after the # in the URL will change.

Comment: @MH2K9 I did read the question. It's indeed not from a variable. However as explained earlier, window.location.hash.replace('#', '') will just remove the # in the url and not give back the part behind that, which was clearly stated in the question.